# Is it possible to create a nested struct array? How?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My goal with this piece of code is to create an array of 1000 positions, containing a struct which contains an int (to be used as a counter) and a nested struct initialized as an array of 100 positions. Am I designing this correctly?

As in, I'm trying to achieve a bidimensional table of 1000 columns by 100 rows, where these 100 rows each have the before mentioned int to be used as a counter/index variable, and each position in the 100 rows array to be comprised by the nested struct! 
This is what I got so far:

```
#define DATA_MAX 1000
#define MAX_CHAR_TIPO_MOV 60
#define MAX_CHAR_DESCRICAO 60
#define MAX_MOVIMENTOS 100
#define BUFFLEN 1024

char buffer[BUFFLEN];

typedef struct{
    int montante;
    int data;
    int periodicidade;
    char tipo[MAX_CHAR_TIPO_MOV];
    char descricao[MAX_CHAR_DESCRICAO];
}sistema;

typedef struct{
int indice;
struct sistema tabela[MAX_MOVIMENTOS]; /* Compiler gives me an error here: array type has incomplete element type */
}movimentos;

movimentos c[DATA_MAX];

/* Function to initialize arrays/structs in order to eliminate junk */


void inicializarfc(movimentos c[])
{
    int i, j;
//percorre o vector estrutura
for(i=0; i<DATA_MAX; i++)
    for(j=0; j<MAX_MOVIMENTOS; j++)
{
    c[i].[j].data = -1;
    c[i].[j].montante = -1;
    c[i].[j].periodicidade = -1;
    memset((c[i].[j].tipo), ' ', sizeof(c[i].[j].tipo));
    memset((c[i].[j].descricao), ' ', sizeof(c[i].[j].descricao));
   }
}
```

If indeed it is possible to create what I'm asking, how should I go about to access the structure members?
Compiling in Codeblocks 10.05 in W7 using GCC.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `struct` keyword in front of a `typedef`.

Just say:

```
sistema tabela[MAX_MOVIMENTOS];
```

To access members, just say:

```
movimentos m;
/* initialize data */
int x = m.tabela[0].montante; // accesses montante field of tabela[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your declarations:

```
typedef struct{
   int montante;
   int data;
   int periodicidade;
   char tipo[MAX_CHAR_TIPO_MOV];
   char descricao[MAX_CHAR_DESCRICAO]; 
}sistema;  

typedef struct{ 
   int indice; 
   struct sistema tabela[MAX_MOVIMENTOS];
}movimentos;
```

The problem is that you're looking for a type named `struct sistema`, but you haven't declared a type like that; instead, you declared an *anonymous* struct type and created a *typedef name* `sistema` for it.  To access a type named `struct sistema`, you would have to provide the struct tag in the definition:

```
struct sistema { ... };
```

The struct tag `sistema` and the typedef name `sistema` live in different namespaces; you could write

```
typedef struct sistema { ... } sistema;
```

and use both `sistema` and `struct sistema` interchangeably, although that would probably be confusing.

In this case, the simplest thing to do is to change

```
struct sistema tabela[MAX_MOVIMENTOS];
```

to

```
sistema tabela[MAX_MOVIMENTOS];
```

in the `movimentos` struct type.